# Add line breaks to a printout of a looong cat string in r

Tags: r, linux, string, cat

I am trying to print out a `ca`" output string longer than a printer line and would like to somehow have line breaks occur at the appropriate points.  There are spaces in the copy.  Here is a string from the cat output:

```
"V125", "V138", "V177", "V191", "V197", "V223", "V229"
```

And here is the command I am using:

```
cat(paste(shQuote(gsa, type="cmd"), 
             collapse=", "))
```

Got this syntax from stackoverflow as I recall.  Line breaks at output time is all I have been looking for, for the last couple days.

I have discovered one kludgey way to get what I need: The "file=" option in cat allows me to create a .txt file containing the cat result which I can then access afterwards and do with as I wish.  But nothing so far as I know in the work stream itself.

Comment: does `scales::wrap_format` do what you want?

Comment: or `base::strwrap()`

Comment: add `\n` in your string for new line

Comment: Tried strwrap but the problem is that cat returns only a NULL - you cannot access the cat output itself.  Same applies to \n - there is no string in the Rstudio work space to put the \n into.